# Why Linq query doesn't return records when querying against partition key in Cosmos Db?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm trying to retrieve records matching a partition key in Cosmos DB. I'm using the following code:

```
//sec.id is Guid, s.key is the partition key (also a Guid)
var query = sectionsContainer.GetItemLinqQueryable<Post>().Where(s => s.type == "post" && s.key == sec.id);
var qdef = query.ToQueryDefinition();
var iterator = postsContainer.GetItemQueryIterator<Post>(qdef);
List <Post> posts = new List<Post>();

while (iterator.HasMoreResults)
{
    var response = await iterator.ReadNextAsync();
    posts.AddRange(response.ToList());
}

return posts;
```

Cosmos DB returns nothing. The SQL query the Linq generates is the following:

```
SELECT VALUE root FROM root WHERE ((root["type"] = "post") AND (root["key"] = "9bb4fcdc-2077-4a0b-9041-81752f06d011"))
```

Which in turn when copy & pasted to Azure Portal's Data Explorer the query returns the correct results:

```
[
    {
        "id": "52d2abbd-d777-4c3c-b02c-a940eb49fdc4",
        "type": "post",
        "key": "9bb4fcdc-2077-4a0b-9041-81752f06d011", //Doesn't work when querying against this
        ...
        "section": {
            "id": "9bb4fcdc-2077-4a0b-9041-81752f06d011", //Works when querying against this
            "type": "section",
            ...
        }
        //Data removed for brevity
    },
    // Second & third item...
]
```

When I modify the query to match [document].section.id == sec.id, Linq / Cosmos DB returns correct data.

The question here is why the query doesn't work when using the partition key but works when using any other property?

Comment: I think we need more info: are you sure that's the generated sql? How did you capture it? Can you show the exact value of `sec.id`?

Comment: You can inspect the generated SQL in debugging mode by inspecting the qdef variable, I'm confident that that SQL is correct. The sec.id variable value is "9bb4fcdc-2077-4a0b-9041-81752f06d011", also confirmed in the debugger and in the generated SQL.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I was just double checking because I am used to more parameter-like link queries.

Comment: &%!#?%!! Of course, the problem was (once again) between the chair and keyboard. The query is generated against "section" container but is run against "posts" container. Only 6 hours of banging the head against the wall.

Comment: .... sorry, but: lol... it happens to all of us ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The problem was between the keyboard and chair.

The query is generated against sections -container but is run on against the posts container.

```
var query = sectionsContainer.GetItemLinqQueryable<Post>().Where(s => s.type == "post" && s.key == sec.id);
var qdef = query.ToQueryDefinition();
//var iterator = postsContainer.GetItemQueryIterator<Post>(qdef); <-- Problem was here.
var iterator = sectionsContainer.GetItemQueryIterator<Post>(qdef); // Now it works
```